# Solving system of set equations

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, elementary-set-theory

Given 
$$
\begin{cases}
A \setminus X = B\\
X \setminus A = C 
\end{cases}
\ \ \ B \subseteq A, A \cap C \neq \emptyset
$$
I'm asked to find  $X$.

My attempt:

$A \setminus X = A \setminus ((X \setminus A) \cup (X \cap A)) = B$

$A \setminus (C \ \cup (X \ \cap A)) = B$

$A = B \cup C \cup (X \cap A)$

$A \setminus (B \ \cup C) = X \setminus \overline{A}$

$(A \setminus (B \ \cup C)) \cup \overline{A} = X$

Is everything correct?

If not, what is the correct solution?

Comment: Have you tried drawing a Venn diagram?

Comment: @Y.Forman Ahh...I didn't because I don't want to draw for all possible set configurations.

Comment: Try drawing just $A$ and $X$ in the general configuration, then identifying $B$ and $C$ on the diagram.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your jump from the second to the third line is unjustified - and the third line clearly cannot be true if $C \cap A = \varnothing$

Instead, start from $X = (X\setminus A) \cup(X\cap A)$. The first term is $C$; the second is related to $B$, see if you can figure out how.

As I mentioned in the comments, I recommend following along a Venn diagram as you derive these equations.

Comment: @FalsePromise But $A \setminus X = B$ implies $B$ and $X$ are disjoint, so we cannot have $X \cap A=B$

Comment: Yea, that was a mistake. I actually ended up with a non convex circle for $X$, i.e. $X$ lies on the outermost level having a gap in the middle which is $B$, this is why I got such result.

Comment: @FalsePromise I'm not sure what you mean. In any case, whatever you see in the diagram, try to follow the reasoning through to the equation manipulation.

Comment: Thank you! Finally came up with answer by drawing diagrams right: $X = C \cup (A \setminus B)$.